# scipy.stats.anderson test critical values

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, statistical-test, scipy.stats

I used `scipy.stats.anderson()` to
test for normal distribution.
my test distribution was not normal distributed,
therefore teststatistic > critical value.
However, when checking all calculated critical values
I observed, that for decreasing p-values critical values are increasing.
That means, the more critical the test (smaller p-values), 
the closer gets the critical value to the test statistic.
Which should be the other way, in my opinion.
Anyone familiar with Anderson Test and its implementation in Scipy?

Answer (score 3):

The last time I did some spot checking, scipy.stats.anderson worked correctly. For Anderson-Darling test against the normal distribution, statsmodels has a function that returns the p-value http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.normal_ad.html

The critical values are for a given significance level. When we want a smaller significance level, then we have to increase the critical values, assuming we are in the right, upper tail of the distribution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance

For example for a z-test, the one-sided upper tail critical values based on the normal distribution are:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> stats.norm.ppf([0.9, 0.95, 0.975])
array([ 1.28155157,  1.64485363,  1.95996398])
```

P-values, in contrast, calculate the tail probability at the given observed value, the larger the observed value, the smaller is the p-value, again in the case of the right, upper tail.

In your example, if the observed value is above the critical value of the 10% level, then it could still be below the critical value of the 5% level. In this case we would reject the null hypothesis at the 10% but not at the 5% level.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Thanks for pointing me to statsmodels. I was actually looking for a function returning the p-value.